# Find the point on the top or bottom of a sequence of numbers

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

I have a problem like this and i would like to write a snippet of code to solve this problem.

1. Sequences like: `[1,2,3,2], [1,3,2], [1,3,2,1]` -> i want to output 3 (maximum) because the sequence increases to 3 and then decreases again
2. Sequences like `[3,2,1,2], [3,1,2], [3,1,2,3]` -> i want to output 1 (minimum) because the sequence decreases to 1 and then increases again

Any idea on how to do this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Try getting local maximas and/or local minimas:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

a = np.array([3,2,1,3])

res=a[np.hstack([argrelextrema(a, np.greater),argrelextrema(a, np.less)]).ravel()]
```

This will return both local maximas and minimas. You can mark them somehow separately, if it's better for your use case. From your question I assumed it can be just one extremum. Also - depending on your data you might consider using `np.less_equal` or `np.greater_equal` instead of `np.less` or `np.greater` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I found it interesting to implement this algorithm in Python 3.
The basic idea is practically to find the minimum and maximum given a sequence of numbers. A sequence, however, can have several maximum points and several minimum points to be taken into consideration. However this is the algorithm I implemented.
I hope it's useful.

```
sequence = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,8,10,1]

index = 1
max_points = [] #A sequence may have multiple points of relatives max
relative_maximum = sequence[0]
for element in range(len(sequence)):
    if(index == len(sequence)):
        break
    if(sequence[element] < sequence[index]):
        relative_maximum = sequence[index]
        change_direction = True
    else:
        if(change_direction == True):
            max_points.append(relative_maximum)
            change_direction = False
    index = index + 1

index = 1
min_points = [] #A sequence may have multiple points of relatives min
relative_minimum = sequence[0]
for element in range(len(sequence)):
    if(index == len(sequence)):
        break
    if(sequence[element] > sequence[index]):
        relative_minimum = sequence[index]
        change_direction = True
    else:
        if(change_direction == True):
            min_points.append(relative_minimum)
            change_direction = False
    index = index + 1

print("The max points: " + str(max_points))
print("The min points: " + str(min_points))
```

> Result: The max points: [5, 10] The min points: [2]